# Sorting data in Firebase (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a todo-list and want to sort it onclick by categories like: author/dateOfCreate/deadline.. 
I'm using Firebase orderBy('property_name') method and first time when I call it in constructor - it works, but when I try to pass different 'property_name' in function below - it doesn't. 
I'm new to this, so will be glad for any advice.
Here's my code:

```
export interface Todo {
  id?: string,
  author?: string,  
  completed?: boolean,   
  dateOfCreate?: number,  
  deadline?: number,  
  todoDescription?: string  
}
```

TodoService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Todo } from '../models/todo'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TodosService {
  todoCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Todo>
  todos: Observable<Todo[]>
  sort: string= 'deadline'

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    console.log(this.afs.collection('todos'))
    this.todoCollection = this.afs.collection('todos', ref => ref.orderBy(this.sort, 'desc'))
    this.todos = this.todoCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Todo
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id
          return data
        })
      })
    )
  }

  getTodos() {
    return this.todos
  }

  sortByAuthor(){
    return this.sort = 'author'
  }
}
```

Todo.component.ts

```
constructor(private todoService: TodosService) { }

sortbyAuthor() {
  this.todoService.sortByAuthor()
}
```

Todo.component.html

```
<button (click)="sortbyAuthor()">Author</button>
```

Comment: when you pass different property here `orderBy(this.sort, 'desc'))`, it doesnt work? What do you get? Also the property needs to exist in the database

Comment: @PeterHaddad It works fine once, in constructor but my function sortByAuthor() doesn't make any changes. (If I change property at the beginning sort: string= 'author' it will sort by authors, so my property exist in the db)

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `sortByAuthor()`, the query is not running, you are just assigning `author` to `this.sort`. That's why there are no changes. You can change the service class to the following:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TodosService {
  todoCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Todo>
  todos: Observable<Todo[]>
  sort: string= 'deadline'

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    console.log(this.afs.collection('todos'));
  }

  getCollection(sort : string){
    this.todoCollection = this.afs.collection('todos', ref => ref.orderBy(this.sort, 'desc'))
    this.todos = this.todoCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Todo
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id
          return data
        })
      })
    )
  }

  getTodos() {
    return this.todos
  }

  sortByAuthor(){
    this.sort = 'author';
    return this.getCollection(this.sort);
  }
}
```